# How to deal with dynamic urls with special characters like single quote?

Tags: encode

I am generating dynamic an "a href" html tag on my asp page. Also the url is dynamic. Sometimes there are special characters inside the url and the hyperlink is not working. For example when there is an single quote:

```
http://myCompany.com/'s-hertog.aspx
```

How can I fix this that the dynamic url always will work?

I already try this, but is not working:

```
string hyperLinkHtml = string.Format("<span class=\"bw-NewsQueryWebpart-BodyItemTitle\"><a href='{0}' >{1}</a>", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(newsItem.Url), newsItem.Title);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by my self. I changed the single quotes to double quotes in the string.format:

```
string hyperLinkHtml = string.Format("<span class=\"bw-NewsQueryWebpart-BodyItemTitle\"><a href=\"{0}\" >{1}</a>", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(newsItem.Url), newsItem.Title);
```